# Wordpress post query on more than one condition

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following function which returns only future events, which works great:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => self::POST_TYPE,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'meta_key'       => 'start_date',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'status'         => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'start_date',
        'value' => date('Ymd'),
        'compare' => '>=',
        'type' => 'DATE'
      )
    )
  );
```

The problem I have is, I also need to check whether a custom field called "post_is_global" has been set (the type is BOOL by the way) but I don't know how to implement it into this query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query should look somewhat like this:

```
$args = array(

    ...

    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => date('Ymd'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'post_is_global',
            'value' => '1',
            'compare' => '=',
        ),
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

References:

- [ACF | Query posts by custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/)
- [Class Reference/WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Great references as well, thank you :) I tried voting up on your answer but it said I need a reputation of a least 15.